# C printf() two strings on one line?

Tags: c++, c

Hello I was wondering if I could output two strings one line like in c++ with

```
cout << "hi" << " person";
```

Comment: `printf( "%s %s\n", "hi", "person");`, although the arguments would normally be variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as same as `cout`, `printf` will put anything that's supplied to it into the output. `cout` or `printf` does not add newlines.

```
printf("hi");
printf(" person");
```

Output:

```
hi person
```

If you are looking to accomplish it with a single statement in C:

```
printf( "%s%s", "hi", " person");
```

For both examples, you will have to `#include <stdio.h>`. (Not necessary for some compilers).

---

### Some extra notes on `cout` : Why can we chain `cout` in C++?

Please note that `cout << "hi" << " person";` is just shorthand for:

```
cout << "hi";
cout << " person";
```

Expanded this way, it is not much different from my first example with two `printf` calls.

`std::cout` is an instance of `std::ostream`. And (simply put,) [`std::ostream` overloads the `<<` operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) such that it can accept a several types and return a `std::ostream` reference back. So the operator `<<` on `std::ostream` is (mostly) same as this function:

```
std::ostream& printThingsToOutput(std::ostream& where, string s);
```

The code you supplied can be broken like this:

```
(cout << "hi") << " person";
```

First, `cout << "hi"` is executed. It send the string `"hi"` to the output buffer, and then returns the `cout` object. Then the rest of the statement becomes:

```
cout << " person";
```

(This also returns a `std::ostream` reference, which is discarded immediately.)

It is because of the fact that overloaded `<<` operator returns the same `std::ostream` reference that we can chain the operations together in the manner you have done.

Answer (score 2):

- Option 1:

  ```
  printf("%s %s", "hi", "person");
  ```
- Option 2:

  ```
  printf("%s", "hi" "person");  // Concatenation is only valid for string literals
  ```
- Option 3: (for string literals only)

  ```
  puts("hi" "person");
  ```
- Option 4:

  ```
  #include <string.h>
  // ............................
  char longbuff[1000] = "hi";
  strcat(longbuff, "person");
  puts(longbuff);
  ```

Comment: If anyone is wondering why option 3 works, it is because whitespace between two strings is concatenation in C.

Answer (score -1):

The function you're looking for is called `puts` and it's declared in `<stdio.h>`.